# How can I enable access of NSURLCredentials when an iOS Device is locked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsurlcredential

I am using a Swagger generated Swift Client which uses `NSURLCredentials` to authenticate with a server. I am using persistence type `.Permanent`
My app communicates with the server in the background and works fine, except when I lock the phone (I see 401 errors in the log). I believe that `NSURLCredential` is not able to access the keychain when the phone is locked.
I came across some posts which talk about enabling keychain access using `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock`. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this with `NSURLCredential`. Does anyone know if and how this can be configured?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly what is happening, in all likelihood.  You have a couple of options:

- Delete the underlying keychain item and recreate it, specifying that it should be accessible when the device is unlocked.  You don't need to use `NSURLCredential` at all with that approach.  Just create an internet password item using Keychain Services APIs and the credential store should pick it up automatically.
- Keep the credential data in memory, and implement the `URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` delegate method in your session delegate (or the equivalent method for NSURLConnection if you're using that API) to provide the credential when asked.